# Archive of old Yahoo groups?

Tags: yahoo-groups

I am looking for an old Yahoo! Group that doesn't exist any more.

In http://archive.org there is nothing to be found either.

Is there a way to get back the contents of [this group](http://de.groups.yahoo.com/group/ffsh/)?